# Stack widget not working as a child of Column widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am unable to successfully make Stack widget to work when i place it as a child of Column widget. My intention is to mix the Stack layout and Column/Row layout methods to reap the benefits of both approach. When i run the code the compile gave a scanty error message:

> ════════ (2) Exception caught by rendering library
>   ═════════════════════════════════════════════════ A RenderFlex
>   overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom. User-created ancestor of
>   the error-causing widget was:    Scaffold
>   file:///C:/Users/admin/AndroidStudioProjects/music_app/lib/main.dart:240:12

Blank white page was returned when i ran the code. What am i doing wrong? The following is the code snippet:

```
 body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
           Container(
             child: Stack(
               children: <Widget>[
                 Positioned(
                   top: 100,
                   left: 50,
                   child: Container(
                     child: Text("Text is Located here"),
                   ),
                 ),
               ],
             ),
           )
          ],
        ),
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is occuring because you wrapped the `Stack` widget with `Container` which expands to the entire screen, if not provided `height` or `width`. So, just provide a custom `height` to the `Container` that will fix the overflow error. Working code below:

```
body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            height: 200,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  top: 100,
                  left: 50,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text("Text is Located here"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

[image]

I provided a test `height`. You may need to provide height or width per your requirement.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:-

```
body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              top: 100,
              left: 50,
              child: Container(
                child: Text("Text is Located here"),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```